# SSIS Package Configuration need reconfiguration

Tags: ssis

i am working in a client server envirnoment.. i have an SSIS package with xml configuration, when i configure it on a client and execute it, it works find, but when i copy that configured package and try to execute it from another client it is not executed and needs reconfiguration, after reconfiguration it works find...
i also try it with sql server configuration and the same problem was also there...

Is there any way that i configure the ssis package on one pc and can be executed from any client, means no need of reconfiguration when i copy it to another client....

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an xml file configuration, you provide a connection to that file. But when you move the package to the new client, you have to have the configuration connection as well. Let alone configuration, you need to have the connections set up properly for each and every object that you reference.

Thats the only reason I can fathom why your packages are failing.

Answer (score 0):

> executed from any client

Quite possibly not. You're going to need valid permissions (database, file system, ??) for the actions your package takes, and simply copying the package and configuration file won't create those automatically.

You might want to create an SSIS proxy account, grant the necessary permissions to the proxy, then run the package using the proxy. If this is all internal, you enable the proxy account on whatever client systems need to run the package.  If you're distributing this to clients, give them instructions for setting up the proxy and they can do the same.